# Can a dict be modified indirectly?

Tags: python, list

Sorry to ask a silly question, but I can't find a complete answer.

With the following:

```
a_dict = {"A":0, "B":0}
def GetElementRef(index):
    return a_dict[index]
would_like_to_modify = GetElementRef("A")
would_like_to_modify = 2
```

This results in `would_like_to_modify` being given the value of 2, while `a_dict` remains unchanged.

AFAIK, any assignment based operation on `would_like_to_modify` just reseats the reference. Is there any way to modify the original dictionary element in this indirect way?

I am aware of a few other ways I can implement this by directly referring to the dictionary, but I'm curious if this can somehow be done.

Comment: Even if you could do this (like using a reference in C++), why would `a_dict` remain unchanged? Surely the assignment `would_like_to_modify = 2` would change `a_dict["A"]`?

Comment: @GregHewgill, it doesn't modify it for me! I am a hobbyist and more familiar with C++, hence the silly unpythonlike ways. I try, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the code in the question, the answer is "no", because the values in the dictionary are numbers, and numbers are immutable. On the other hand, if the values were mutable, they can indeed be changed. For example:

```
a_dict = {"A":[0], "B":[0]}

def GetElementRef(index):
    return a_dict[index]

would_like_to_modify = GetElementRef("A")
print would_like_to_modify
> [0]

would_like_to_modify[0] = 2
print would_like_to_modify
> [2]
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for both bearing with me and providing me with a potential option! Champion among men.

Comment: You're welcome :) . Please remember to accept the answer that was most helpful for you, by clicking the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an object without having a reference to that object. You don't have a reference to the object you wish to modify (the dictionary), so the answer to your question is no.

You can modify an object *in* a dictionary so long as it's a mutable type (for example, if a dictionary item is a list, you can change it) but the dictionary itself can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the standard method of a_dict[index] = "something"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between objects and variables. In python, an object is a "physical" entity with a memory representation of its data and a table of methods that can be called on it. A variable, on the other hand, is simply a reference to an object, and has no physical identity of its own (unlike, say, C, where a pointer is still a thing that you can take the address of independently of the object it points to).

Now let's look at the code you posted. When you say

```
a_dict = {"A":0, "B":0}
```

you have a dictionary object, `a_dict`, that contains references to four other objects, arranged in two key-value pairs.

When you say

```
def GetElementRef(index):
    return a_dict[index]
would_like_to_modify = GetElementRef("A")
```

now `would_like_to_modify` and one of the value slots of `a_dict` both refer to the same object (ignoring for the moment that a number is not truly an object). However, when you say

```
would_like_to_modify = 2
```

you are *rebinding* the variable `would_like_to_modify` to a different object, not modifying the value it points to.

Basically, when a variable is used as an rvalue, it is transparently replaced by the object it refers to, whereas when it is used as an lvalue it is bound to the object on the right hand side of the =. Similarly, a_dict["A"] is a reference, and when it is used as an lvalue, you can rebind it to a different object, but when it is used as an rvalue it is transparently replaced by the value it refers to, and the fact that you accessed it via `a_dict["A"]` is lost.

The key point is that `=` is an operator that does strictly one thing - it binds a reference to an object. Now if you look at the code Óscar López posted above:

```
a_dict = {"A":[0], "B":[0]}
```

and rewrite it a bit

```
num1 = 0
key1 = "A"
value1 = [num1]
num2 = 0
key2 = "B"
value2 = [num2]

a_dict = {key1 : value1, key2 : value2}
```

you can see that there are seven objects involved, two integers, which are immutable, two strings, two arrays each with a reference to one integer, and a dict, with references to two strings in its key slots, and two arrays in its value slots. The following interactive session is instructive:

```
In [1]: num1 = 0

In [2]: key1 = "A"

In [3]: val1 = [num1]

In [4]: num2 = 1

In [5]: key2 = "B"

In [6]: val2 = [num2]

In [7]: dict = {key1: val1, key2: val2}

In [8]: dict
Out[8]: {'A': [0], 'B': [1]}

In [9]: num1 = 4

In [10]: val1
Out[10]: [0]

In [11]: dict
Out[11]: {'A': [0], 'B': [1]}

In [12]: val1 = [6]

In [13]: dict
Out[13]: {'A': [0], 'B': [1]}

In [14]: val2[0] = 42

In [15]: val2
Out[15]: [42]

In [16]: dict
Out[16]: {'A': [0], 'B': [42]}
```